# Will simple copying files over mac os x installation actually save the system?

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery

I'm having a macbook with freshly installed os x mavericks. I also have a disk with my yet to be working copy of mac os x with all my documents and software installed.

Unfortunately this disk won't get mounted by Mac OS X, and I can't just run migration assistant to copy those files.

But this disk easily mounts by linux in readonly state.

So the question is.

Can I just copy all files from my old disk over the new one to get my old copy of OS X working correctly?

Comment: No _DDs_. This won't help. No _“Recovery HD”_ boots: this won't mount disk either.

Comment: You have a filesystem that's broken in some undetermined way. There's no way anyone can reasonably predict what will happen. How can anyone know if every last file you need from this broken filesystem is readable and uncorrupted?